# how to get the encrypted bot data from the azure datatable in decrypted format

Tags: azure, botframework

I created QNA bot using Bot Application(visual C#)and bot framework.Bot state data is stored in Azure data table. But the data of the conversation(user typed data) is encrypted in Azure data table. I want to decrypt that. How can I decrypt that?

Comment: Why do you want that? What is your purpose in doing that? Because you probably would not want to read the conversation state directly from data table. If you want to save something in the conversation state and read later, there are APIs for that. Also state data saved in data table are not encrypted per se.

Answer (score 0):

> the data of the conversation(user typed data) is encrypted in Azure data table. I want to decrypt that. How can I decrypt that?

If you’d like to retrieve **ConversationData** after you store it, you can refer to the following code:

```
context.ConversationData.SetValue<string>("testval", "hello world");

string mes = "";

context.ConversationData.TryGetValue<string>("testval", out mes);
```

Besides, the conversation history are stored with the below structure in Azure table storage, if you’d like to retrieve conversation history and extract the data from `Activity0`, you can try the following code:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RetrieveHistory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={your_account_name};AccountKey={your_account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("{your_botconversationhistory_table_name}");

            TableQuery<MessageEntity> query = new TableQuery<MessageEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "emulator|61b59bkmceee"));

            foreach (MessageEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
            {
                string myactivity = "";
                using (var msi = new MemoryStream(entity.Activity0))
                using (var mso = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var gs = new GZipStream(msi, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        gs.CopyTo(mso);
                    }
                    myactivity = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mso.ToArray());
                }

                Activity activity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(myactivity);

                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
                    entity.From, entity.Recipient, activity.Text);
            }



            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        public class MessageEntity : TableEntity
        {
            public MessageEntity(string pk, string rk)
            {
                this.PartitionKey = pk;
                this.RowKey = rk;
            }

            public MessageEntity() { }

            public string From { get; set; }

            public string Recipient { get; set; }

            public byte[] Activity0 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Properties and Types:**

[image]

**Example entity:**

[image]

**Note**: you can create a Console Application and install the following packages, and do a test with the code I provided to retrieve history.

*packages.config:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bot.Connector" version="3.13.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="9.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thank you. May I know, what do you mean by {your_storage_account} ?

Comment: Replace it with your StorageConnectionString to access table via WindowsAzure.Storage sdk.

Comment: when I add CloudStorageAccount ,CloudTableClient, CloudTable,TableQuery,MessageEntity and QueryComparisons, I am getting errors. So what can i do for that??

Comment: Did you install [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/8.7.0) client library?

Comment: underlined error. There is no such classes(CloudStorageAccount ,CloudTableClient, CloudTable,TableQuery,MessageEntity and QueryComparisons) to add.

Comment: Hi @YaduskaThambiaiyah, I updated the reply and shared the complete code and my packages.config, you can create a Console Application to test it.